# How to solve this circuit with capacitors and inductors?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I was wondering if you can help me to solve this circuit:

[image: Circuit]

I need to calculate the voltage in the capacitor (wC) and the voltage in the inductor (wL), also I need to calculate the voltage across each element in the circuit and the current through each element in the circuit.

I think I need to apply Ohm's law for the capacitor and Ohm's law for the inductor:

$$I=C\frac{dv}{dt}$$

and:

$$V=L\frac{di}{dt}$$

I almost got all the answers from the solutions book:

[image]

But the problem is that I don't know why there is 100 V in the capacitor and no voltage in the resistor next to it. Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: Those are two separate circuits. There's no way the voltage on the left upper node can influence the voltage on the right upper node and vice versa as they are separated by a current source. Does this help?

Comment: Since there's no switch or time information given, it seems like the circuit is in steady-state.  So what do you know about a DC circuit with inductors and capacitors in steady state?

Comment: The answer in the red box for inductor current is wrong.

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. Show your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the steady state, the voltage across capacitor will not change (capacitor is fully charged). If dv/dt is 0 then current through capacitor is 0 which is same as current through the resistor next to it. Hence there is no voltage drop in the resistor next to it.

Now the 2A coming from the current source will completely pass through 50\$\Omega\$ in steady state. So voltage drop across 50\$\Omega\$ is 100V which is same as that across capacitor as none of it drops across 20\$\Omega\$.

You can also solve this in the following way. The two circuits are unrelated in the sense that there is no relation between the voltage at the two nodes of the current source.

Considering each circuit as different, the left circuit receives 2A current while the right one receives -2A.

Now the circuits reduce to parallel RC and LR circuits. Capacitor will be an open circuit in steady state (dv/dt = 0) as no current can flow through it. Inductor will ve short in steady state as there is no voltage across it in steady state (di/dt = 0). Now it is quite easy to figure out the manitudes of currents and voltages across each element in steady state.